# Does Quickbooks has to be installed along with the SDK?

Tags: quickbooks

I am currently setting up a connection to Quickbooks.

Here is the enterprise setup:

- A typical domain controller has the Quickbooks database (QBW file)
- Quickbooks Enterprise Server 10 is installed on the server.
- The client for Quickbooks is not installed on the server.
- The Quickbooks SDK 10 is installed on the server.

I am trying to use the SdkTestPlus3 that is provided with the Quickbook SDK 10. I am getting the following error:

> -2147220433  The requested connection type could not be found.

Does the Quickbooks client has to be installed on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QuickBooks client has to be installed on the machine the SDK application is installed on, yes.